# Decoding JSON in Swift and Ignoring Not Available JSON Properties/Keys

Tags: ios, swift

I am having issues with decoding JSON, where some of the fields returned from the server as not available on the client. Take a look at the following code. The JSON consists of three roles but the Role enum only consists of student and staff. How can I successfully decode JSON ignoring the missing faculty role.

```
let json = """
[
{
   "role": "student"
},
{
   "role": "staff"
},
{
   "role": "faculty"
},
]
"""

struct User: Decodable {
    let role: Role
}

enum Role: String, Decodable {
    case student
    case staff
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case student = "student"
        case staff = "staff"
    }
}

let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(decoded)
```

Currently, I get the following error:

```
error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "role", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Cannot initialize Role from invalid String value faculty", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: `try!` is the worst choice. `catch` the error and handle it.

Comment: try! is just used for testing purposes. I just want to ignore the missing case. This means it should not throw an exception, it should just ignore the missing case.

Comment: This is what `catch`ing the error does. Or use `try?` with Optional Binding. And the `CodingKeys` are not needed if the cases match the raw values.

Comment: Either fully define the enum or implement custom decoding though `init(from: Decoder)`

Comment: @vadian Catch won't help here; it prevents the exception but you don't end up with a decoded object.  As I understand it, the OP still wants a decoded object they just want to exclude certain enumeration cases.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you elaborate by providing a code example please?

Comment: Information on decoding manually is in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) and there would be many other tutorials or examples I am sure.   Personally I would fully decode the JSON by correctly defining the enum and then filter the array to remove the unwanted values.

Answer (score 0):

It will always throw that error because the decoder will be presented with "role": "faculty" which it won't recognize. Thus if you really really want to ignore it you can ditch the decoder and do something like this:

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json.data(using: .utf8)!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] else {return}
let users: [User] = json.filter({$0["role"] != "faculty")}.map({User(role: Role(rawValue: $0["role"])!)})
```

Or you can add the missing case and filter the array:

```
users = users.filter({$0 != Role.faculty})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a top-level object to hold the `[User]`:

```
struct UserList {
    var users: [User]
}
```

Then, give it a custom decoder that will check for malformed `role` keys and ignore those Users, but won't ignore other errors:

```
extension UserList: Decodable {
    // An empty object that can decode any keyed container by ignoring all keys
    private struct Ignore: Decodable {}

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

        var users: [User] = []

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            do {
                // Try to decode a User
                users.append(try container.decode(User.self))
            }
            // Check for the specific failure of "role" not decoding.
            // Other errors will still be thrown normally
            catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context)
                        where context.codingPath.last?.stringValue == "role" {
                // You still need to decode the object into something, but you can ignore it.
                _ = try container.decode(Ignore.self)
            }
        }

        self.users = users
    }
}

let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserList.self,
                                       from: json.data(using: .utf8)!).users
// [User(role: Role.student), User(role: Role.staff)]
```

If you define `User.CodingKeys`, then you can skip the Ignore struct:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    // The auto-generated CodingKeys is private, so you have to
    // define it by hand to access it elsewhere
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case role
    }
    let role: Role
}
```

With that, you can get rid of the Ignore struct and replace this line:

```
_ = try container.decode(Ignore.self)
```

with:

```
_ = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: User.CodingKeys.self)
```